# How to force a div out of it's parent in mobile with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a row class inside a col class using bootstrap 4 which looks perfect on desktop, but for mobile I want to force the row to be below it's parent row when the page is viewed on mobile. So technically I want to 'break out' of it's parent without changing the height of the parent. Here's an example of what I have currently on desktop:

[image: Desktop]

And what I'm trying to achieve on mobile:

[image: Mobile]

My code is just basic bootstrap with no additional CSS changes:

```
<div id="jumbo" class="row">
    <div id="info" class="col-xl-6 col h-100">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="info-text" class="col offset-md-2">
          <p class="display-4">Estate planning made easy</p>
          <p>
            Let’s get a clear plan in place for your money,<br> 
            property and other assets here and now.<br> 
            It’s never too early to protect what’s important<br>
            to you and your family.
          </p>
          <p class="museo-sans-900">Get your free personalised report in just 20 minutes</p>
          <button class="btn btn-brand-secondary">Start Now</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: but you will end with an empty parent?

Comment: I think you can with `absolute` positioning. But then it will have to have a fixed height to the child and fixed padding-bottom to the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make two versions of the section. One like the first one and one like the second. Then put id=#desktop for the first and id=#mobile for the second . Then be sure to mark #desktop{display:none} for @media only screen and (max-width: (insert width of mobiles)), and #mobile{display: none} for min-width: (insert width of mobiles) . It s a long way, but if you don t find another easier way you can try this.